# About definition of superset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I have read definition of **superset** somewhere as *"a set containing all elements of a smaller set."*. This implies that for set A to be a superset of B, B must be a proper subset of A, that is, A must contain at least one element which is not in B. Does it mean that a set A cannot be a superset of itself? or does there exist terms such as **Superset** and **Proper Superset**?

Comment: There is no implication that $B$ has to be a proper subset of $A$.

Comment: The problem of defining mathematical terms in English is that of creating confusion.

$A$ must contain all elements of $B$ does not entail it should contain elements not in $B.$

Also, I'd always say $A$ contains $B$ as opposed to $A$ is superset of $B.$

Comment: The use of the word "smaller" is misleading and unnecessary, and the author who writes it that way should be chastised.

Comment: $A$ being a superset of $B$ is equivalent to $B$ being a subset of $A$.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine : Does it mean that every set is a superset of itself?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine : I have read it from Wolfram Mathworld site.  
"https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superset.html"  
They have also used the term Proper Superset.  
"https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperSuperset.html"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, $A$ is a superset of $B$ exactly when $B$ is a subset of $A$.  $$A\supseteq B \iff B\subseteq A$$

Likewise $A$ is a proper superset of $B$ if and only if $B$ is a proper subset of $A$.

$$A\supsetneq B\iff B\subsetneq A$$

Answer (score 3):

Notation and terminology can vary, but here at least the terminology is pretty much uniform. $A$ is a superset of $B$ if every element of $B$ is an element of $A.$ This does not preclude the case where $A=B$. $A$ is a proper superset of $B$ if it is a superset and it has at least one element that is not in $B$ (i.e. $A\ne B$). So any set is a superset of itself, but not a proper superset.

The first sentence on [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superset.html) is somewhere between misleading and wrong and you should ignore it (the linked page on proper superset is also poorly-worded in my opinion).

Additionally, be warned: their notation $A\subset B$ for proper subset/superset, despite the clear analogy with $<$ vs. $\le,$ is not quite standard. Often, $A\subset B$ is just used to denote subset/superset and $A\subsetneq B$ is reserved for proper subset/superset. The notation $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$ that Graham uses in his answer is what I prefer as well since it removes any ambiguity.

Comment: Let any set A is a subset of any other set B, then it will be either an improper subset of B or a proper subset of B. So, are you suggesting that to remove ambiguity one should prefer A⊊B  notation for proper subsets and  A⊆B notation for improper subsets? And should one avoid using ⊂ symbol, except for general purpose?

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra The only "improper" subset of a set is the set itself. But if we know they are equal, we just say $A=B.$ The point of the $A\subseteq B$ is to say that $A$ is a subset of $B$... which means it is either a proper subset or equal... we don't know or aren't saying which. Whereas, $A\subsetneq B$ means that $A$ is is a proper subset... we are including the information that it is not equal.

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra (You will almost never hear somebody say "$A$ is an improper subset of $B$"... it's just not something that makes much sense to say. You either mean "$A$ equals $B$", in which case, say that, or you are choosing a very confusing way of saying "$A$ is a subset of $B$ that is not necessarily proper" which in turn is a very confusing way of saying "$A$ is a subset of $B$."  )